# Handling a null parameter in Express JS route

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have a URL that has three arguments:

`/fruit/:arg1/:arg2/:arg3`

When I pass it:

`/fruit/apples/oranges/bananas`

everything is good.

But if I pass it:

`/fruit/apples//bananas`

it doesn't work because `arg2` is empty.  How do you handle this?

```js
app.get('/fruit/:arg1/:arg2/:arg3', function(req, res) {
  console.log("url=" + req.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a regex

```
app.get(/\/fruit\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/, function(req, res) {
  var arg1 = req.params[0];
  var arg2 = req.params[1];
  var arg3 = req.params[2];
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Another solution I came up with is to add multiple routes with and without the args and had them call a function with the args.  It works but it's messy.